# Union of a sorted linked list algorithm

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

This is the first part which I have done already:

Let A and B be sorted arrays with all elements of A distinct and all elements of B distinct (though elements can occur in both A and B). Design an O (n) algorithm that produces a sorted array C containing all elements of A and B without repetitions. For instance, if A = [1, 2, 5, 7] and B = [2, 5, 10], C = [1, 2, 5, 7, 10].

But I'm stuck with this part to do with list:

Solve the same exercise for the case where A and B are linked lists.

My code:

```
    Merge(A,B,C)
     i=0;
     j=0;
     k=0;
     while (i < A.length && j < B.length)
          if (A.content <= B.content)
               C.content = A.content
               k = k + 1; i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is incomplete: it does not tell what to do when `A.content > B.content`. The approach is nearly identical to the well-known algorithm for merging two sorted collections, with the exception that when two items are equal you advance both collections.

Using linked lists does not change the algorithm, because in both cases you operate on a single "head" element from each collection.

```
merge-lists(list a, list b) -> list c
    while !a.at-end && !b.at-end
        if a.head < b.head
            c.add( a.head )
            a.move-next
        else if a.head > b.head
            c.add( b.head )
            b.move-next
        else // it means that a.head == b.head
            c.add( a.head )
            a.move-next
            b.move-next
        end
    while !a.at-end
        c.add( a.head )
        a.move-next
    while !b.at-end
        c.add( b.head )
        b.move-next
```

Comment: Thank You what is the head is it the content

Comment: @EmmanuelYohannes That's the element of the linked list at the current iteration point.